# Add Array as a dictionary value

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, alamofire

I am trying to post some parameters to server like this :

```
["name":"john" , "age":"25"]
```

but there is `key/value` which requires a set of array, called `tags`, when I add it to dictionary like this

```
tagsArray = ["#tag1" , "#tag2" , "#tag3"]

["tags":tagsArray] as [String:Any]
```

my app crashes due to this error :

> -[Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000234080
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray
>   dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x600000234080'

How should I add Array in dictionary's value ?

**Edited:**

```
let parameters = ["hash":appDefaults.getUserHash() ,  "string": vHash , "media_title":vTitle , "description":vDescription , "Keywords[]":insertTagArray] as [String : Any]

            Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

                 multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "photofileupload",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")

                for (key, value) in parameters {
                    multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
                }
            },
                             to:URLserver)
/// rest of code
```

Comment: Could you provide some more code, looks like your converting the dictionary to data?

Comment: @NeilFaulkner check edited Q

Comment: What types are appDefaults.getUserHash(), vHash, vTitle etc.... all strings?

Comment: @NeilFaulkner yes all of them are string

Answer (score 0):

When you loop through the dictionary, it crashes because you're trying to encode the array not the strings inside the array. You should also loop through the array of strings and encode them. You can try doing this:

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

        multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "photofileupload",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")

        for (key, value) in parameters {

            if let tagsArray = value as? [String]{

                let stringsData = NSMutableData()
                for tag in tagsArray{
                    if let stringData = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                        stringsData.appendData(stringData)
                    }
                }

                multipartFormData.append(stringsData), withName: key)
            }
            else if let stringValue = value as? String{

                multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)

            }

        },to:URLserver)

    }
```